# Practice Exercises for C# (Learning Path)

Tags: c#

I am looking for some exercises or small tasks (Similar to one we get in exams). I have a book which teaches the theory and some example and I do get the Idea from the text but I need exercises to get satisfaction that I really know the basics and syntax etc. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this, http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/teasers.html, from Jon Skeet, one of the gurus. Thought it might be a little bit advanced, it might be worth trying it out

Edit: Adding [SPoj](http://www.spoj.pl/) after reading [this  SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933909/where-is-the-best-algorithm-exercises-like-euler-project)

Comment: Ugh, #1 in this blew my mind.

Comment: @Zai: And I just realized myself that trying to answer Stack Overflow user questions helps me refresh my concepts,clarify my understanding and gives me an opportunity to see how others would solve the same problem from their point of view :). Getting  actively involved in SO is one more way you can be assured that you know what you think you know, in addition to trying out programming  puzzles

Comment: Ram, You are definitely right. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You could try [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) or Dave Thomas' [Code Kata](http://codekata.pragprog.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I would give [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) a shot.