# where is the best algorithm exercises like euler project?

Tags: algorithm

I need learn some algorithms. What is the best collection of algorithm exercises that is like Project Euler?

Comment: What's wrong with Project Euler?  Have you solved them all?

Comment: LOL, have you solved them all. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are the ones that I know of, which are good and are used by many programmers.

[Spoj](http://www.spoj.pl)
[Top Coder](http://topcoder.com)
[Code Chef](http://www.codechef.com/)
[USACO](http://ace.delos.com/usacogate)

Thanks

Comment: Also [rosalind](http://rosalind.info/problems/locations/)

Answer (score 2):

Try [Spoj](http://www.spoj.pl/), it lets you use a large variety of languages and run and compile them online.